# How can I change the characters used to display trees under npm ls?

Tags: windows, cmd, terminal, npm

I'm trying to diff the package versions that a coworker is using. When running `npm ls`, mine look like this:

```
+-- grunt-contrib-concat@1.0.1
| +-- chalk@1.1.3
| | +-- ansi-styles@2.2.1
| | +-- escape-string-regexp@1.0.5
| | +-- has-ansi@2.0.0
| | | `-- ansi-regex@2.0.0
```

but his look like this:

```
├─┬ grunt-contrib-concat@1.0.1
│ ├─┬ chalk@1.1.3
│ │ ├── ansi-styles@2.2.1
│ │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.5
│ │ ├─┬ has-ansi@2.0.0
│ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
```

We're both using Windows. I tried to explicitly define my encoding as UTF-8 but nothing changed.

Is this configurable somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that my co-worker is using [the `--unicode` flag](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#unicode).

> When set to true, npm uses unicode characters in the tree output. When false, it uses ascii characters to draw trees.

He must have also configured it in his `.npmrc` file.